# Discord.js Check Every Roles Permissions of a Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a command that gets every channel and role from a server id that the bot is in, then for each channel/role, it copies everything the server id has and creates it. I am having problems getting the permissions of every role in the channels when creating the channel. When I try to execute this command gives me an error of `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.`

```
 if (command === 'clone') {
          let guild = args[0]
     let findguild = client.guilds.cache.get(guild)
     let findguildchannels = findguild.channels.cache.forEach(c => message.guild.channels.create(c.name, { type: `${c.type}`,  permissionOverwrites: c.permissionOverwrites.map(v => ({
                    id: message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role =>(role.id)),
                    allow: v.allow,
                    deny: v.deny
                })), userLimit: c.userLimit}))
    let findguildroles = findguild.roles.cache.forEach(c => message.guild.roles.create({
        data: { name: `${c.name}`,  color: '#' + c.color.toString(16), permissions: c.permissions.toArray() }
    }))
  console.log(findguildchannels)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had just needed to do this

```
 if (command === 'clone') {
          let guild = args[0]
     let findguild = client.guilds.cache.get(guild)
    let findguildroles = findguild.roles.cache.forEach(c => message.guild.roles.create({
        data: { name: `${c.name}`,  color: '#' + c.color.toString(16), permissions: c.permissions.toArray() }
    }))

         let findguildchannels = findguild.channels.cache.forEach(c => message.guild.channels.create(c.name, { type: `${c.type}`, permissionOverwrites: c.permissionOverwrites.map(v => {
                            let target =  message.guild.roles.cache.get(v.id);
                            if (!target) return;
                            return {
                                id: message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === target.name),
                                allow: v.allow,
                                deny: v.deny
                            };
                        }).filter(v => v), userLimit: c.userLimit}))
  console.log(findguildchannels)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord has a Server Template feature already

[image: Discord Server Template]

Comment: This doesn't answer my question and it makes a whole new server and not make channels in the existing server id ...